# Running this code results in an empty list, could someone possibly see an error in my code? Thanks

Tags: python

```
def every_payday(year):
    # this method will get every "weekly" payday for the given year 
    d = date(year, 1, 1)
    d += timedelta(days = 4 - d.weekday())
    while d.year == year:
        yield d
        d += timedelta(days = 7) # since payday is weekly or every 7 days
# getting the date for today and defining a table to append the list of paydays to 
        today = date.today() # current day 
        table = []

        for d in every_payday(2022):
            table.append(d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        print(table)
```

Comment: with what param do you run it ? and how ? [edit] and share the code that calls

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Put minimum code to reproduce the issue, for example, the necessary libraries, `date` method etc.

Comment: Ow, are the 4 final lines the main code ?

Comment: `timedelta(days = 4 - d.weekday())` is capable of producing a *negative* delta (and does so in your code, for 2022).  When that happens, `d` starts off at a day near the end of the previous year, so the `while` loop immediately exits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When giving `2022`

```
# d is 2022-01-01
d = date(year, 1, 1)

# remove 1d, as d.weekday() is 5, so remove 4-5=-1
d += timedelta(days=4 - d.weekday())
# d is 2021-12-31

# 2021 != 2022 : code ends
while d.year == year:
```